# Numpy Element-wise Standard Deviation

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have `n` 2-dimensional matricies `M1, M2, M3, ...` all with the same dimensions.

Is there an efficient way to produce an output matrix `MR` where each element in `MR` corresponds to the standard deviation of the elements in that position in `M1, M2, M3, ...`

An example of the operation follows:

```
       1 4 5   8 2 3   -1 8 2      4.73  3.06  1.53
stdev( 3 9 2,  2 1 0,   0 3 1 ) =  1.53  4.16  1.00
       7 1 2   8 3 1    9 5 8      1.00  2.00  3.79
```

To clarify: the top left element of the resultant matrix is calculated as follows:

```
stdev(1,8,-1) = 4.7258
```

Whereas the bottom left element is calculated as:

```
stdev(7,8,9) = 1.00
```

If this is not a way to do this with built-in operators in one go is there an efficient alternative?

Here are the test matrices:

```
a=numpy.array( [[1,4,5],[3,9,2],[7,1,2]])
b=numpy.array( [[8,2,3],[2,1,0],[8,3,1]])
c=numpy.array([[-1,8,2],[0,3,1],[9,5,8]])
```

Comment: You could please be a bit more specific, which numbers you use to calculate your standard deviation. E.g, it is not clear to me, which numbers you use to obtain a std. dev. of ``1.00``.

Comment: I've endeavoured to clarify @Dietrich.

Comment: Ah, it's degrees of freedom issue, @lejlot. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numpy` is your friend

```
import numpy as np
print np.std((a,b,c), axis=0, ddof=1)
```

for provided matrices it gives

```
array([[ 4.72581563,  3.05505046,  1.52752523],
       [ 1.52752523,  4.163332  ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.7859389 ]])
```

as expected

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: Yep, just caught that.

Answer (score 1):

First put your data into one array:

```
d = np.dstack((a,b,c))
```

Than take the std along the thrid axies:

```
np.std(d, 2, ddof=1)
```